# Call a function before Delete happens in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

I need to call a function to determine whether its a folder or file before the Delete function is called.

I am using File Watcher to know all the changes made inside my default Folder.
I need to get the type of the item deleted(File or folder) using the path.
But since the folder/file is already deleted I get an error with the path(The path could not be found!) as the file/folder is already deleted.

Is there a way to get the type of the item deleted before its deleted using File Watcher or any other method ?

This is my function for determining a file or Folder.This function is called inside the Delete event(filewatcher.Deleted) in file watcher.

```
private static bool IsDirectory(string path)
{
    System.IO.FileAttributes fa = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(path);
     bool isDirectory = false;
     if ((fa & FileAttributes.Directory) != 0)
     {
         isDirectory = true;
     }
     return isDirectory;
}
```

Hope my question is clear enough ! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** This is not possible to do in any reasonably easy manner, but you might be able to work around it by doing something "similar enough".

You can't do this directly with managed code since `FileSystemWatcher` only reacts to changes that have already been made, by which point the file has been deleted and you can't query information about it.

Theoretically you could implement this in unmanaged code by writing a DLL and injecting it into all processes that might delete the files you are interested in; the DLL would hook appropriate Win32 functions -- a good choice would be the (undocumented) `NtSetFileInformation` which is the lowest-level function called when a file is to be deleted -- and retrieve the information you are interested in before the deletion happens. Of course this is going to be quite hard and very involved, so in practice it might not be an option at all.

A workaround you might want to try is to cache information about the contents of your directory (e.g. remember all subdirectories that exist inside it) and then retrieve the "was that a directory?" information from your cache. If that's all you need and you can tolerate a false negative every now and then it should be reasonably easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is it possible to block the default delete function in windows and call the delete function from my application?(this question raised after going through your answer. :) )

Comment: @user3222297: *Purely theoretically* it might be (not sure), but it would still involve injecting your code into all processes that you want to modify like that and you would have to provide a communication channel to your own app, write what is effectively a server and so on. You *really* don't want to go there.